# How to change the windows mode to maximize while the app is running?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

When the user click on restore down i want to go back to maximize.  If is posible, is there any way to disable the restore down button or to return to maximize mode in UWP?

[image]

I try to use:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize)
```

but it does not work(the size seems to be bigger than).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the user click on restore down i want to go back to maximize. If is posible, is there any way to disable the restore down button or to return to maximize mode in UWP?

The `CoreWindow.SizeChanged` event will be invoked, when you click on restore down button. And you could execute `TryEnterFullScreenMode` method to maximize the app view if the current View is not `FullScreen` mode.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.SizeChanged += CoreWindow_SizeChanged;
}

private void CoreWindow_SizeChanged(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var appView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    if (!appView.IsFullScreen)
    {
        appView.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
    }
    args.Handled = true;
}
```

Note: The app view will blink, because the `TryEnterFullScreenMode` method gets executed after view size gets changed and the view will be resized quickly.

Comment: Can i enter to fullscreen mode but still be able to show the Microsoft Windows taskbar?

Comment: The Microsoft Windows taskbar will disappear, when the app enter full screen mode.

Comment: Maximize and full screen are different. I think because of the size of the task bar is not fixed (could be at bottom or side or top), there is no consistent way to maximize the app grammatically.